# Connection $1$-forms values in $\mathfrak{gl}(r,\Bbb R)$?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, $E \to M$ a vector bundle of rank $r$ and $\nabla$ a connection on $E$.

The connection can be uniquely determined locally on a $(e_i)$ framed open set $U$ by $$\nabla_X e_j=\sum\omega^i_j(X)e_i$$ where $\omega^i_j(X)$ are the connection $1$-forms.

Its being claimed that these $1$-forms can be encoded in a single $1$-form $\omega$ with values in the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{gl}(r,\Bbb R)$. Could anyone shed some light on this why wold this take values on $\mathfrak{gl}(r,\Bbb R)$?

Comment: This is the idea of a [Principal Connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_(principal_bundle)#Formal_definition). Note that the connection one form is defined on the total space of the frame bundle $F(E)$ rather than over $M$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a vector bundle $E\to M$ of rank $r$ and a $TM$-connection $\nabla$ on $E$
$$\nabla\colon\mathfrak{X}(M)\times \Gamma(E)\longrightarrow\Gamma(E),\ (X,s)\longmapsto\nabla_Xs,$$
for each choice of a local frame $\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_r$ of $E\to M$ defined on an open subset $U\subseteq M$, there exists a unique $1$-form $\omega$ on $U$ with values in the vector space $\mathfrak{gl}(r,\mathbb{R})$ of $n\times n$ matrices, i.e. $\omega\in\Omega^1(U)\otimes_\mathbb{R}\mathfrak{gl}(r,d)$, or equivalently a $C^\infty(U)$-linear map $\mathfrak{X}(M)\to C^\infty(U)\otimes_\mathbb{R}\mathfrak{gl}(r,\mathbb{R}),\ X\mapsto\omega(X)=(\omega_{ij}(X))$, such that $$\nabla_X\sigma_j=\sum_{i=1}^r\omega_{ij}(X)\sigma_i,\ \ \text{for all}\ j=1,\ldots,r, \text{and}\ X\in\mathfrak{X}(M).$$

Comment: I find this identification $\omega(X) = (\omega_{ij}(X))$ a bit counterintuitive. Shouldn't $\omega(X)$ be a map $U \to \Bbb R$? @agt

Comment: For each $j=1,...,r$, $\nabla_Xe_j$ is a local section of E defined on $U$, and decomposes in terms of the local frame $e_1,\ldots,e_r$. The coefficients of this decompositions, let us call them $\omega_{i j}(X)$, can be seen as the entry of $r\times r$ matrix, let us call it $\omega(X)$, which is smoothly depending on the point of $U$.

Comment: I also corrected a typo in my  answer

Comment: Above I forgot to say that the coefficients of the decomposition, the $\omega_{ij}(X)$ are ordinary (real-valued) smooth functions on  $U$, i.e. smooth maps $U\to\mathbb{R}$. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: $\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}$$\mathfrak{gl}(r,\R)$ is the space of $r$-by-$r$ real matrices. At each $p \in U$, the connection $1$-forms $\omega_{ij}$ define a linear map
\begin{align*}
T_pM &\rightarrow \mathfrak{gl}(r,\R)\\
X &\mapsto \begin{bmatrix} \omega_{11}(X) & \cdots & \omega_{1r}(X) \\ \vdots & & \vdots \\ \omega_{r1}(X) & \cdots & \omega_{rr}(X) \end{bmatrix},
\end{align*}
i.e., a $\mathfrak{gl}(r,\R)$-valued $1$-form.